# Jave error: reached end of file while parsing (Not typical)

Tags: java, arrays, math, methods

Im trying to create a method to find the common factors of 2 given numbers but I can not get the file to compile. All of my curly brackets are closed as I'm aware thats usually almost always the cause of this error. Hopefully someone can help me out!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class E1{
   public static void main (String [] args){  
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      double n1,n2;

      System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
      n1=kb.nextDouble();
      n2=kb.nextDouble(); 

      printCommonFactors(n1,n2);
   }

 //call a method that prints the positive shared factors of the 2 inputed numbers

    public static void printCommonFactors(int n1,int n2){

    //determining the max/min of the two inputed variables

        int max,min;
        max=Math.max(n1,n2);
        min=Math.min(n1,n2);

    //setting up 2 arrays to store the factors

        int [] maxFactors = new int [max];
        int [] minFactors = new int [min];      
        int counter1;

        for (inti=0;i>max;i++)
            if (i%max=0)
                    counter1++;
                    maxFactors[counter1]=i;


        for (int i=0;i>min;i++)
            if (maxFactors[i]%min=0)
                maxFactors[i]=

    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

[image]

Comment: Please share the exact error you recieve

Comment: You can't create an array with the size of a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the "reached end of file while parsing" is that the parser expects to find a right-hand-side operand for the equals operator but fails to do so. You end your method with `maxFactors[i]=`. Binary operators always require right-hand-side operands. In this case, you must place a value after the equals-sign.

Also, it looks like you are trying to apply some principles to Java that you probably pulled from another language. The most obvious one here is that you use replace explicit blocks with white-space. This works for languages like Python, but does not work in Java. Indentation is not significant in Java and only has the effect of improving readability.

This is relevant for your `for` statements. Because you are not actually using blocks, these statements are actually equivalent:

```
for (inti=0;i>max;i++)
    if (i%max=0)
        counter1++;
        maxFactors[counter1]=i;

for (inti=0;i>max;i++) {
    if (i%max=0) {
        counter1++;
    }
}
maxFactors[counter1]=i;
```

This will cause issues with `i` being referenced out of its scope. The other issue with this is that the `for` initializer (`inti=0;`) is missing a space and should be `int i = 0`.

Other issues include trying to allocate arrays with a non-integer size (must be of type `int`) and using bad test expressions for your `for`-loops (`i>min` will invariably remain true if it is *ever* true due to your incrementor until an integer overflow is reached).